# Unlisting a column of a database

Tags: r

I have a dataframe output named Returns with two columns- date and R1R2. The second column is a list because of which i am unable to carry out any further operations on the dataframe(including write.table). How can i convert it to a dataframe that will have first row as Date (same as now) and second as a vector containing the elements of the list.

For eg: my output dataframe is of the following format(second column is a list):

```
Date            R1R2
22-06-2014      c(0.98,0.87,.96,.79)
23-08-2014      c(0.88,0.98,.67,.86)
```

Is it possible to convert the second column to a vector in the same dataframe?

I tried the following code to convert the list to a vector

```
a <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=2))
y <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(Returns$R1R2))
{   
   y[i] <- unlist(R1R2$x[i])
   a <- a[i, (y[i])]
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
  Error in a[i, (y[i])] : incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In y[i] <- unlist(R1R2$x[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In y[i] <- unlist(R1R2$x[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Can anyone help me with this. 
Or split it into multiple columns. For eg:

```
Date           1        2     3      4
22/06/2014    0.98    0.87   .96   .79
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(Date=c("22-06-2014","23-08-2014"),
                 R1R2=I(list(c(0.98,0.87,.96,.79),c(0.88,0.98,.67,.86))))

df$R1R2 <- paste(unlist(df$R1R2),collapse=",") # converting list to a vector
```

And

```
library(splitstackshape)

df2 <- concat.split.multiple(df, split.cols = "R1R2", seps = ",") # splitting to multiple columns
```

Comment: @so, the above commands both do work, But the output they give is wrong. I want the R1R2 values corresponding to the particular date next to the corresponding Row. ie, i want 22-06-2014       0.98,0.87,.96,.79
23-08-2014      c0.88,0.98,.67,.86 However, the above command gives me a vector of all elements of R1R2 and repeats the same in all rows. ie (in the above context, it gives this:
23-08-2014   0.98,0.87,.96,.79,0.88,0.98,.67,.86.  How can i correct it?

Comment: @user3509579, does 510947's sample data match the structure of your data? As the "splitstackshape" package author (and the `cSplit` function author) I'd like to make sure there's nothing wrong with the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does my function l2df maybe help converting the list to a data.frame?

```
install.packages("berryFunctions")
library(berryFunctions)
?l2df
```

The examples should give you a good idea of how to use it.
Then afterwards, you can use

```
cbind( YourDateVector,  TheNewDFobtainedWithBerrysAwesomeHelperFunctionl2df  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` approach (Provides the desired output with the optimal speed)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(R1R2 = unlist(R1R2)), by = Date]
#          Date R1R2
# 1: 22-06-2014 0.98
# 2: 22-06-2014 0.87
# 3: 22-06-2014 0.96
# 4: 22-06-2014 0.79
# 5: 23-08-2014 0.88
# 6: 23-08-2014 0.98
# 7: 23-08-2014 0.67
# 8: 23-08-2014 0.86
```

In case you have more than two columns and you want to unlist `R1R2` and that all the rest of the columns will match the right `R1R2` values, use this great `cSplit` function (uses `data.table` package too)

```
library(devtools)
source_gist(11380733)
res <- cSplit(df, "R1R2", sep = ",", direction = "long")
res[, R1R2 := gsub("\\(|\\)|c|\\s", "", R1R2)]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton everybody! I am still learning R and these functions made my task so much easier.

Comment: If one of these answered your question, you should probably check the checkbox on the left of it